# Service Worker parameterization

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker

I am just getting around to implementing a SW for a client with very sketchy connectivity, and so intercepting ALL post, patch, put requests for eventual resolution is a priority. However there are also similar requests to an api outside of my control, and those should not be proxied - I only want to proxy requests to my api. What is the preferred approach within a SW to achieve this?

I've considered passing my api url as a parameter (obviously I have to support dev, test, and prod sites at a minimum) but not sure of the best way to do this. Is putting the url into indexeddb a decent approach?

Thanks for any good ideas!

Comment: Can you share your current service worker code?

Comment: I don't have any code right now beyond the very basic method definitions. I'm wondering about an approach more than anything,